# How to add an SLD as a custom domain to firebase?

Tags: firebase, subdomain, custom-domain

I have hosted a react-app project on firebase. I now want a custom domain "example.club.code" which is a second level domain to redirect to this project I just hosted. However after I put in "example.club.code" as shown below:

[firebase custom domain input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rldBP.png)

I click on continue and I get this problem:

[firebase custom domain verification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeSxH.png)

Firebase seems to automatically get rid of the first part of the domain leaving just "club.code" instead of "example.club.code".

My question is how do I stop firebase from doing that?

I have tried reading around on this but I can't seem to find a solution for it. I tried hosting it on vercel but I don't really know bout it much so I rather have it on vercel.